# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$$

So we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n^2}})$$

Using the squeeze  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+n^2}})\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n^2}})\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+1}})$$

But $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+n^2}})=0$ and  $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+1}})=1$

Is there a finite limit to the series?

Comment: Actually $lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+n^2}})= \infty$, so the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You have the sum of $n^2$ terms, each of them being $\geq \frac{1}{n}$. It follows that the limit is clearly $+\infty$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio is there a theorem that say that if $a_n\leq b_n$ and $a_n\to \infty$ then $b_n \to \infty$?

Comment: If $a_n\to \color{red}{+}\infty$ and $b_n\geq a_n$ it is obvious that $b_n\to +\infty$, you do not need a name for that, you only need the definition of *positively divergent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 
$$L_1=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n+n^2}}\rightarrow \infty \ne 0$$
and.
$$L_2=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \rightarrow \infty \ne 1.$$
This does not prove anything. This limit is divergent as shown by @Yves Daoust.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}\sim\int_1^{n^2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+n}}=2(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n+1})\sim2n.$$